# Using non-variable in file path

Tags: file, variables, static, path, textures

I want to make the file path changeable by the user. But as far as I can tell it has to be static in order to do so. Here is what I got.

```
private String texturePath;
more code...
public String getTexturePath()
{
return (String)texturePath;
}

public void onUpdate()
{
super.onUpdate();
this.texture = "/adventure/" + this.getTexturePath() + ".png";
}
```

There are multiple objects, and when using a static variable it changed all of theirs to the same, without being able to change them individuality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send as a parameter to the method.

```
public void onUpdate(String path){
    super.onUpdate();
    this.texture = path + this.getTexturePath() + ".png";
}
```

Static vars belong to the class, not to the instances.

Comment: That didn't work. Adding (String path) to the onUpdate stop it from overriding its extension's onUpdate

Comment: Well, you need to adapt the rest of your code so. For sure if this method is overriding something, then you need to make other adjustments. My answer was based on only that snippet.

Comment: There is other way, that actually I don't like because it seems you need this var just for this method... If you don't want to change the method signature (from update() to update(String path)), just create a "private String path", with get/set methods for that var, and set the var value before calling your method. Then, the method would stay like: 
public void onUpdate(){
    super.onUpdate();
    this.texture = this.getPath() + this.getTexturePath() + ".png";
}

Comment: Still having no luck I am trying to update in game the texture pulling from the clip board this did work: public static String getClipboardString()
    {
        try
        {
            Transferable var0 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents((Object)null);

            if (var0 != null && var0.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
            {
                return (String)var0.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception var1)
        {
            ;
        }

        return "";
    } and this.texture=getcli